# How to implement this as a array using vuejs?

Tags: php, arrays, json, vue.js, codeigniter-3

I need append this html block with create vue object using this input box values.  how to do that? can you explain what ever answer please.
with below html append using vuejs part.if anyone know how to do this please answer this.I am trying to add and delete one row at a time but two things i am not sure about.

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="octo-form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Select  Column</label>
      <select v-model="condition_column" class="form-control m-input" id="new_where_column_name">
        <option value=""></option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="octo-form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Aggr Fun</label>
      <select v-model="aggFunc" class="form-control m-input" id="new_logical_conditions">
        <option value="SUM">SUM</option>
        <option value="AVG">AVG</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <div class="octo-form-group">
      <label for="sel1">Condition</label>
      <select v-model="col_condition" class="form-control m-input" id="new_logical_conditions">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="<">&lt;</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label for="sel1">Type</label>
    <div class="input-group condition-type-form">
      <input v-model="type" type="text" class="form-control" aria- label="Text input with dropdown button">
      <select>
        <option>Type </option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i want like this array this inputs and append this values with block.

```
array : {
     column:'',
     condition:'',
     aggfun: '',
     type:''
}
```

Comment: https://jsbin.com/bomavadune/1/edit?html

Comment: tlike this example. but not exactly this

Comment: so your trying to submit a form? meaning, send the data to your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

http://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/514974/

```
data: {
fields:[
{
key:1,
name:'column',
values:["Hello","There"],
selected:"Hello"
},
{
key:2,
name:'aggFunc',
values:["Hey","You"],
selected:"Hey"
}
]}
```

and in Vue Template did it like this

```
<div class="octo-form-group" v-for="item in fields">
       <label for="sel1">Select  Column</label>
       <select v-model="item.selected" class="form-control m-input" 
              id="new_where_column_name">
            <option :value="option" v-for="(option,idx) in item.values" :selected="idx==0">{{option}}</option>
       </select>                  
    </div>
```

What I'm doing here is I am keeping the data in an array of objects, in which you have options and selected values.

Comment: can create this html block using button click?

Comment: what do you mean by that?